# Appending two lists

Tags: list, recursion, ocaml

So this is one way to append two lists:

```
let rec append l1 l2 =
  match l1 with
  | h :: t -> h :: append t l2
  | [] -> l2
```

But I am trying to write  a tail-recursive version of append. (solve the problem before calling the recursive function).

This is my code so far, but when I try to add append in the first if statement the code becomes faulty for weird reasons.

```
let list1 = [1;2;3;4]
let list2 = [5;6;7;8]

let rec append lista listb =
  match listb with
  | h :: taillist -> if taillist != []  then 
  begin 
    lista @ [h];
    (* I cant put an append recursive call here because it causes error*)
  end else
  append lista taillist;
 | [] -> lista;;

append list1 list2;;
```

Comment: That `!=` shouldn't be used as it's a "physical" comparison. You want to do a structural comparison using `<>`. Also, this kind of test could be put directly in the pattern matching.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to transform a non tail-recursive list algorithm into a tail-recursive one, is to use an accumulator. Consider rewriting your code using a third list, that will accumulate the result. Use cons (i.e., `::`) to prepend new elements to the third list, finally you will have a result of concatenation. Next, you need just to reverse it with `List.rev` et voila.

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of completeness, there is a tail-recursive `append`:

```
let append l1 l2 =
  let rec loop acc l1 l2 =
    match l1, l2 with
    | [], [] -> List.rev acc
    | [], h :: t -> loop (h :: acc) [] t
    | h :: t, l -> loop (h :: acc) t l
    in
    loop [] l1 l2
```

I would recommend to solve [99 problems](http://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/99problems.html) to learn this idiom.

Answer (score 3):

A version using constant stack space, implemented with a couple of standard functions (you'll get a tail-recursive solution after unfolding the definitions):

```
let append xs ys = List.rev_append (List.rev xs) ys
```

Incidentally, some OCaml libraries implement the `append` function in a pretty sophisticated way:
(1) see [core_list0.ml](https://github.com/janestreet/core_kernel/blob/master/src/core_list0.ml) in the Core_kernel library: search for "slow_append" and "count_append"
(2) or [batList.mlv](https://github.com/ocaml-batteries-team/batteries-included/blob/master/src/batList.mlv) in the Batteries library.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of comments on your code:

1. It seems like cheating to define a list append function using `@`, since this is already a function that appends two lists :-)
2. Your code is written as if OCaml were an imperative language; i.e., you seem to expect the expression `lista @ [h]` to modify the value of `lista`. But OCaml doesn't work that way. Lists in OCaml are immutable, and `lista @ [h]` just calculates a new value without changing any previous values. You would need to pass this new value in your recursive call.

As @ivg says, the most straightforward way to solve your problem is using an accumulator, with a list reversal at the end. This is a common idiom in a language with immutable lists.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative tail-recursive solution (F#) leveraging continuations :

```
let concat x =
  let rec concat f = function
  | ([], x) -> f x
  | (x1::x2, x3) ->  concat (fun x4 -> f (x1::x4)) (x2, x3)
  concat id x
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to go about it, like some have said would be to reverse the first list, then recursively add the head to the front of list2, but the top comment with code uses an accumulator, when you can get the same result without it by `::` to the second list instead of an accumulator

```
let reverse list =
  let rec reverse_helper acc list =
    match list with
    | [] -> acc
    | h::t -> reverse_helper (h::acc) t in
  reverse_helper [] lst;;

let append list1 list2 = 
  let rec append_helper list1_rev list2 =
    match list1_rev with
    | [] -> list2
    | h :: t -> append_helper t (h::lst2) in
  append_helper (reverse lst1) lst2;;
```

Answer (score 1):

While ivg is correct that using an accumulator is probably the easiest method for achieving `append` in constant stack space, continuation passing is another way of accomplishing the same.

```
let append lst1 lst2 =
  let rec append' lst1 lst2 k =
    match lst1 with
    | [] -> k lst2
    | x::xs -> append' xs lst2 (fun i -> k (x :: i))
  in
  append' lst1 lst2 Fun.id
```

Here we have `append'` that takes the two lists as arguments *and* a function. We use this argument to build up a function that will actually do the work. It will not actually be *called* until we hit the exit condition, which is the first list being empty.

Let's look at a breakdown of what happens if we make a call with "small" data:

```
append [1; 2] [3; 4]
append' [1; 2] [3; 4] Fun.id
append' [2] [3; 4] (fun i -> Fun.id (1 :: i))
append' [] [3; 4] (fun i -> (fun i -> Fun.id (1 :: i)) (2 :: i))
(fun i -> (fun i -> Fun.id (1 :: i)) (2 :: i)) [3; 4]
(fun i -> Fun.id (1 :: i)) (2 :: [3; 4])
Fun.id (1 :: 2 :: [3; 4])
1 :: 2 :: [3; 4]
[1; 2; 3; 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler solution:

```
let rec apptr l k =
    let ln = List.rev l in
    let rec app ln k acc = match ln with
        | [] -> acc
        | h::t -> app t k (h::acc) in
    app ln k k
;;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way you could do this, using recursion, without using the `@` operator:

```ml
let rec concat l1 l2 =
  match l1 with
  | [] -> l2
  | h :: t -> h :: concat t l2
;;
```

It is simple and has a linear complexity, which depends on the length of the first list.

Answer (score -1):

A possible answer to your question could be the following code :

```
let append list1 list2 = 
 let rec aux acc list1 list2 = match list1, list2 with 
  | [], [] -> List.rev(acc)
  | head :: tail, [] -> aux (head :: acc) tail []
  | [], head :: tail -> aux (head :: acc) [] tail
  | head :: tail, head' :: tail' -> aux (head :: acc) tail (head' :: tail')
 in aux [] list1 list2;
```

It's pretty similar to the code given by another one of the commenters on your post, but this one is more exhaustive, as I added a case for if list2 is empty from the beginning and list1 isn't